# Disabling Python nosetests

Tags: python, nosetests

When using nosetests for Python it is possible to disable a unit test by  setting the test function's `__test__` attribute to false. I have implemented this using the following decorator:

```
def unit_test_disabled():
    def wrapper(func):
         func.__test__ = False
         return func

    return wrapper

@unit_test_disabled
def test_my_sample_test()
    #code here ...
```

However, this has the side effect of calling wrapper as the unit test. Wrapper will always pass but it is included in nosetests output. Is there another way of structuring the decorator so that the test will not run and does not appear in nosetests output.

Answer (score -18, accepted):

I think you will also need to rename your decorator to something that has not got test in. The below only fails on the second test for me and the first does not show up in the test suite.

```
def unit_disabled(func):
    def wrapper(func):
         func.__test__ = False
         return func

    return wrapper

@unit_disabled
def test_my_sample_test():
    assert 1 <> 1

def test2_my_sample_test():
    assert 1 <> 1
```

Comment: Why not delete this post and earn your 'peer pressure' badge?

Comment: Why is this so heavily downvoted? The reasoning is unclear.

Comment: The down-vote reasoning is based on a combination of two things: (1) the answer should be something like "don't implement your own decorator when reading the docs (or source code) would have shown you that it's already available" and (2) still this answer got accepted.  This answer could have been _helpful_ if it only read: avoid using `test` in the decorator name.

Comment: This is a poorly reinvented wheel.

Comment: I don't think you can delete an answer once someone already gave it comments and a vote

Comment: maybe stackoverflow  needs a better way to list two valid solutions and order them in based on the number of up votes. The one question one solution model is not ideal in many aspects of the software development. That's treating software development like maths which is not.

Answer (score 156):

Nose already has a builtin decorator for this:

```
from nose.tools import nottest

@nottest
def test_my_sample_test()
    #code here ...
```

Also check out the other goodies that nose provides: https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing_tools.html

Comment: Test will be just not run and not mark as skipped... Sometimes would be more useful to raise SkipTest exception, as was suggested in @Anders Waldenborg answer, so would be able to see in results that some tests were skipped.

Comment: This is graceful, as one may inherit from a `@nottest` class, and can still mark the descendant as `@istest`. I believe I've been all over the place looking for how to achieve this behavior, and this is the only one that works without tearing the code apart. (Nesting the descendant class to avoid nose's tracker makes the whole thing look terrible :/ )

Answer (score 75):

You can also use [`unittest.skip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.skip) decorator:

```
import unittest


@unittest.skip("temporarily disabled")
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    ...
```

Comment: Works perfectly well with nose too, and also on functions. Great! See http://pybites.blogspot.fr/2009/03/unittest-now-with-test-skipping-finally.html

Comment: This also works great with parameterized tests using the `@parameterized.expand()` decorator from `node_parameterized`... as long as you put `@unittest.skip()` *below* the other -- ie. so that the unittest decorator runs before the parameterized decorator.

Comment: I usually use @unittest.skipIf(True, 'SkippingTests message'), it gives some flexibility, chance to make conditional skip.

Answer (score 32):

There also is a skiptest plugin for nosetest, which will cause the test show in test output as skipped. Here is a decorator for that:

```
def skipped(func):
    from nose.plugins.skip import SkipTest
    def _():
        raise SkipTest("Test %s is skipped" % func.__name__)
    _.__name__ = func.__name__
    return _
```

Example output:

```
$ nosetests tests
..........................................................................
..................................S.............
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 122 tests in 2.160s

OK (SKIP=1)
```

Comment: Or you can just `raise SkipTest` at the start of your test. Note also that you can do `from nose import SkipTest`.

Comment: Note the documentation for this: _"Usually you can use TestCase.skipTest() or one of the skipping decorators instead of raising this directly."._

Comment: raise SkipTest, is good way to dynamically decide if the test is running or skipping. Ugly part, if you are using Jenkins,is writing to junit.xml, and it writes with general tags.

Answer (score 10):

**You can just start the class, method or function name with an underscore and nose will ignore it.**

`@nottest` has its uses but I find that it does not work well when classes derive from one another and some base classes must be ignored by nose. This happens often when I have a series of similar Django views to test. They often share characteristics that need testing. For instance, they are accessible only to users with certain permissions. Rather than write the same permission check for all of them, I put such shared test in an initial class from which the other classes derive. The problem though is that the base class is there only to be derived by the later classes and is not meant to be run on its own. Here's an example of the problem:

```
from unittest import TestCase

class Base(TestCase):

    def test_something(self):
        print "Testing something in " + self.__class__.__name__

class Derived(Base):

    def test_something_else(self):
        print "Testing something else in " + self.__class__.__name__
```

And the output from running nose on it:

```
$ nosetests test.py -s
Testing something in Base
.Testing something in Derived
.Testing something else in Derived
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

The `Base` class is included in the tests.

I cannot just slap `@nottest` on `Base` because it will mark the entire hierarchy. Indeed if you just add `@nottest` to the code above in front of `class Base`, then nose won't run any tests.

What I do is add an underscore in front of the base class:

```
from unittest import TestCase

class _Base(TestCase):

    def test_something(self):
        print "Testing something in " + self.__class__.__name__

class Derived(_Base):

    def test_something_else(self):
        print "Testing something else in " + self.__class__.__name__
```

And when running it `_Base` is ignored:

```
$ nosetests test3.py -s
Testing something in Derived
.Testing something else in Derived
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

This behavior is not well documented but the code that selects tests [explicitly checks for an underscore at the start of class names](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/blob/6f9dada1a5593b2365859bab92c7d1e468b64b7b/nose/selector.py#L72).

A similar test is performed by nose on function and method names so it is possible to exclude them by adding an underscore at the start of the name.