# How do you ignore a static method in nose (nosetests)?

Tags: python, nose

Unlike [instance methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1843106/448876), attempts to ignore a static method *directly* using [`@nottest`](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/testing_tools.html?highlight=nottest#nose.tools.nottest) or [`__test__ = False`](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/finding_tests.html?highlight=__test__) do not work with nose.

Example with `@nottest`:

```py
from nose.tools import nottest

class TestHelper:
    @nottest
    @staticmethod
    def test_my_sample_test_helper()
        #code here ...
```

Example with `__test__ = False`:

```py
class TestHelper:
    @staticmethod
    def test_my_sample_test_helper()
        __test__ = False
        #code here ...

    # Or it could normally be set here.
    # test_my_sample_test_helper.__test__ = False
```

So how are static methods ignored in nose?

Answer (score 0):

In order to ignore a static method in nose, you must set the decorator or property *on the class* containing the static method.

Working example with `@nottest`:

```py
from nose.tools import nottest

@nottest
class TestHelper:
    @staticmethod
    def test_my_sample_test_helper()
        #code here ...
```

Working example with `__test__ = False`:

```py
class TestHelper:
    __test__ = False

    @staticmethod
    def test_my_sample_test_helper()
        #code here ...

# Or it can be set here.
# TestHelper.__test__ = False
```

**Caveat:** this will ignore all methods in the class. As depicted here, use a test helper class.